# What's the significance of a dot before brackets in a template, eg name.errors?.['required']

Tags: javascript, angular

[Angular's form validation docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) have the following code example:

```html
  <div *ngIf="name.errors?.['required']">
    Name is required.
  </div>
```

Syntax like `name.errors?['required']` I've seen, makes sense.

Syntax like `name.errors?.required` I've seen, makes sense.

Combining the dot with the bracket `name.errors?.['required']"` I haven't seen. It doesn't appear to be valid Javascript in Chrome, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['`. What's it do?

Comment: It is valid in Chrome, unless you're running an old version.

Comment: @Aurast you're right, seems to be working, not sure what I did to get the error. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's just another syntax of [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

> Syntax like `name.errors?['required']` I've seen, makes sense.

That's actually invalid syntax! It will be evaluated as a ternary (eg `a ? b : c`, just missing whitespace) and will throw an error `requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression`. The correct syntax is with the dot

`name.errors?.['required']`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zjy17n?file=src/app/app.component.html